# Pre-Loading Images with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a slideshow in the banner of my webpage. The images in this slide show can be somewhat large (>0.5MB). Because of this, I want to pre-load the images as much as possible. In an attempt to do this, I've written the following code:

```
var bgs = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png" ];
var bgi = 0;
var bgimg = null;

var isInitLoad = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#bannerTable").each(function () { $(this).fadeOut(15); });
  $("#bannerTable").fetchImage();
});

$.fn.fetchImage = function () {
  var image = bgs[bgi];
  var imageUrl = "/images/" + image;

  return this.each(function () {
    var $obj = $(this);
    $obj.fadeOut(250, function () {
    $obj.css('background', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')').fadeIn(250);

    bgi = bgi + 1;
    if (bgi >= bgs.length) {
      bgi = 0;
    }

    if (isInitLoad) {
      setInterval(getNextImage, 3000);
      isInitLoad = false;
    }
  });
});
}

function getNextImage() {
  $("bannerTable").fetchImage();
}
```

Unfortunately, my images are not being preloaded. How do I write my code such that:
1) The bannerTable fades in as soon as the first image is downloaded
2) Continue downloading the other images so they are pre-cached

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

in fetchImage() try using Image object for precaching images.